# ErrorType: Argument to path.join must be string

Tags: phonegap-plugins

i am working on phonegap application to send sms using third party plugin.but i am facing an exception "ErrorType: Argument to path.join must be string:360:15". 
please tell me what the reason of this exception!

here is snapshot of error
 [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si2fK.jpg)

before this exception i was facing missing of plugin.xml file exception. after add of plugin.xml i am facing this error now. let me help to debug this, i will be thank full of you in advance